# Requirements on Time dimension to enable YTD operators

Tags: mdx, olap, mondrian

I am looking for references that can answer the following two questions:

Does YTD work for all versions of Mondrian?

What are the requirements on the Mondrian and physical schema to enable the YTD operator in
MDX queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit too vague.

Every version? No idea, but it works for Mondrian 3 and Mondrian 4. I don't think you want to look  further back than that.

The time dimension has to be defined as `type="TimeDimension"` on the schema and the levels must have a `levelType` attribute (see documentation). I recommend that at least year, month and day levels are defined.

You should have the time dimension as a separate database table, but that's not required. It does, however, improve performance.